# Cleanly wrap a legacy class with lots of overloads behind an asp.net webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a class which I need to expose via a WebAPI. However, the class has around ten overloads of the same method, ranging from four parameters up to around 12! I’m not in a position to change this underlying class as the change would be too significant for other reasons so I’m trying to neatly wrap this behavior as best I can.

I don’t want to have to write 10 methods on both the client side (caller) and the server (webAPI) matching these method signatures 1:1, but can’t think of a more elegant way to do this.
To better explain my problem I have a class:

```
Class A{
Public string something(int a, int b, int c, int d){}
Public string something(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e){}
Public string something(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f){}
Through to…
Public string something(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h, int I, int j, int k, int l){}
}
```

Obviously they aren’t all ints and it isn’t this clean as there are various combinations of parameters in this legacy class.

I don’t want to have to write a GET method in both my new client side wrapper that calls out to my API, and a GET method inside my API itself to receive every parameter, but can’t think of a cleaner or more elegant way to do it.

Ideally I’d like to pass some sort of params object/dictionary to the caller which is then passed to the web API, but don’t know if webapi would support this in an HTTP GET?

Any suggestions or feedback is welcomed on how to best approach this.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
// Create an EmployeeDTO that will be used as the model, 
//i.e. parameter of your controller action
    public class EmployeeDTO
    {
        public int a { get; set; }
        public int b { get; set; }
        public int c { get; set; }
    }

    // Create a factory that does the actual work 
    // of calling one of your Employee constructor
    public class EmployeeFactory
    {
        public Employee GetEmployee(EmployeeDTO eDTO)   
        {
            //based on what values you recieve in the model i.e. EmployeeDTO, 
            //call the appropriate Employee Constructor
        }
    }

    // Your legacy class
    public class Employee
    {
        public Employee(int a) { }
        public Employee(int a, int b) { }
        public Employee(int a, int b, int c) {}
        //.. and so on
    }
```

you can use nuget package `webapiproxy`, `webapiproxy.csharp` for the client to have a proxy js/class